# Clustered SAN volumes not showing up in Windows Explorer

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, failovercluster

Occasionally my drives will not show in Windows Explorer even though they appear online (Reserved) and mapped to a drive letter in Disk Management. I'm not sure what makes them come back but right now I have no way to get to them.

I'm remoted in to the active node and even if I try typing the drive letter in in Windows Explorer (e.g. `K:\`) I still can't get to the drive. The passive node doesn't show them either, in case you're wondering.

I recently switched my SQL Server 2012 cluster (Windows Server 2008 R2) SAN from a VNX to an XtremIO but not sure it's related to the problem. I never noticed the problem before though.

I'm not using Cluster Shared Volumes as far as I know (the SMB share thing...I'm definitely talking about volumes shared across two clustered servers).

UPDATE 12/22/15: I discovered that if I remote in with a different account (same permissions) I can see all the drives. I'm still baffled.

Comment: What exact type of SAN LUNS are you talking about?

Comment: Not sure, what are my options?

Comment: Where should I be then? Are you asking if they are SSD's, RAID type, what?  No need to be a dick.

Comment: Who's the dick? we make it super clear when you sign up for this site that this place is for professional sysadmins, we'd know - or could go and find out - any of the most basic aspects of any questions were were asking. Your question title's second word is 'SAN' yet you have no idea about what type you have - is if FC, FCoE, iSCSI, shared-SAS, Infiniband, FICON etc. This is the ABC's of what we do and you don't know them, hence my concern.

Comment: I do know, it is FC.  I stand by my previous statement. Before my post was edited by @Coops it said " I'm still somewhat of a newbie to clustering and I'm a DBA, not a sysadmin." If this disqualifies me from posting go ahead and downvote or ask for it to be removed, but I'm sure the answer will be useful to others and that's the point of this site.

Answer (score 1):

If it's not a clustered shared volume and you can access it via a drive letter, that means it's a file server resource. Therefore, you will only be able to access it via drive letter on the server that currently hosts that resource. Look to see who is the other of the file server in the Failover Cluster Manager Console.

Comment: Maybe my terminology is wrong. They are volumes that are shared across the cluster with mapped drive letters (they are not using the SMB share thing that started in Windows Server 2012 clustering). It's not a file server resource and neither physical server can see it.